# Get unicolor background navigation bar in Beamer's singapore theme

Tags: beamer, formatting, color

I would like to get the background color of the navigation bar in a single color rather than the default color gradient. Is there any way to do this?

[image: This shows the color gradient in the navigation bar on top of the frame]

Comment: Did you look for another theme with solid colours on top bars? See here: http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The other themes do either have another type of navigation bar (e.g. tree) or sidebars. So I didn't find a suitable one.

Answer (score 4):

`Singapore` uses a vertical shading defined as

```
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
  {%
    color(0cm)=(bg);
    color(1.25cm)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
  }
```

To get a solid color, you can redefine the shading to use only one color, as the following example demonstrates (of course, instead of `structure.fg!25!bg` you can use whatever color you wish):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  {
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
  }
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
  {%
    color(0cm)=(structure.fg!25!bg);
    color(1.25cm)=(structure.fg!25!bg)%
  }
  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=}
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]